# ShadowJar: How to include specific directories?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, jar, shadowjar

I am developing a java application using `org.jdesktop.appframework`.
However the fat jar using ShadowJar is producing files I don't want in my jar.
How can I remove all files except my project classes and the jdesktop dependency?

Using the following task modification does **NOT** include org.jdesktop.appframework somehow:

```
shadowJar {
    include 'myproject/', 'org/'
}
```

result:

```
META-INF/
myproject/
```

expected:

```
META-INF/
myproject/
org/
```

Comment: what other files are included and how where they added in the project?

Comment: @cfrick resources like png, .txt files, ... hard to explain - basically I am copying resources to the compiled classes folder. Then ShadowJar still produces those resources into the root directory which I want to delete.

Comment: If you place something in the resources folder it's expected to be handled like all the other things that are supposed to end up in the root classpath. If those resources are part of your project, why do you not want to be in the fatjar?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [documentation](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/filtering/), the include takes one pattern at a time.

```
shadowJar {
   include '*.jar'
   include '*.properties'
   exclude 'a2.properties'
}
```

Something like

```
shadowJar {
  include 'myproject/' 
  include  'org/'
}
```

(not tested - will do later)

Comment: Sure you will...